# Textbox dont allows null value in ASP .Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, casting

i have column in database with Int data type, but textbox don't allows null. it gives error "Input string was not in a correct format".

```
objinsert.VehGrpID = Convert.ToInt32(txtVehGroupID.Text);
```

Comment: try this objinsert.VehGrpID = Convert.ToInt32(string.string.isnullorempty(txtVehGroupID.Text)?"0":txtVehGroupID.Text.toString());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TryParse instead.

```
int GrpID = 0;
int.TryParse(txtVehGroupID.Text, out GrpID)
if(GrpID > 0)
  objinsert.VehGrpID = GrpID;
```

Comment: You probably want an `else` on this, or else the value of `VehGrpID` won't get set to `null`, as it sounds like the OP wanted.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen now no need of else, hope so.

Comment: @SaiKalyanKumarAkshinthala but it enters 0, it should be enter blank

Comment: @BrijeshSonagara, I didn't get what you are asking? You want 0 if even the textbox is Blank?

Comment: i dont want 0 if textbox is blank

Comment: Shall the database allows null values into GroupID column?

Comment: @SaiKalyanKumarAkshinthala yes

Answer (score 0):

You can just special-case out empty values. I am, of course, assuming here that an empty value should map to `null`.

```
objinsert.VehGrpID = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtVehGroupID.Text) ? null : (int?)Convert.ToInt32(txtVehGroupID.Text);
```

You'll also want to adjust your code to set the textbox's text accordingly.

Your question is also a bit unclear, because you say the textbox won't allow nulls, but you haven't shown us any code that adjusts the textbox text.

Comment: IsNullOrWhiteSpace gives error "string does not contain a defination for IsNullOrWhiteSpace"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `DBNull.Value` Field. If a database field has missing data, you can use the `DBNull.Value` property.

check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
int VehGrpID = Convert.ToInt32(txtVehGroupID.Text);
```

OR

```
int VehGrpIDtxtVehGroupID.Text = int.Parse(txtVehGroupID.Text);
```

The Text property of your textbox is a String type, so you have to perform the conversion in the code.